# Exchangelib - Get meeting organizer mail

Tags: python, email, organizer, exchangelib

I'm currently using the exchangelib library in python. I would like to compare the mail of the account connected to exchangelib and the mail of a meeting organizer. I can have the account mail by typing "account.primary_smtp_address" but I don't know how I could get the meeting organizer mail.

For now i can only get the organizer's name by typing "item.subject" where "item" is my meeting.

Conversely, is it possible to get the account's name (the complete name: "Michael JORDAN" for example) which I could compare with the meeting organizer's name.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meeting organizer is available on `CalendarItem` objects as `item.organizer`.